# MaxGCEPDVolumeCount in Google Container Engine

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Now you can have more than 16 persistent disks attached to a Google Compute Engine node that uses a standard instance type. When using Kubernetes (GKE) there is a limit (`MaxGCEPDVolumeCount`) which defaults to 16.

I tried changing it by settings `KUBE_MAX_PD_VOLS` in `kube-env` but it is not working. How should I properly increase KUBE_MAX_PD_VOLS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually not as simple as changing `MaxGCEPDVolumeCount`, because the new limits are [per-machine-type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#pdspecs). Since a cluster can have nodes with different machine types, kubernetes needs support in the scheduler to understand how many disks can be attached on a per-node basis. That support is being [worked on](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24317) and will be available in a future release.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In the meantime is there a way to set KUBE_MAX_PD_VOLS in GKE if all the nodes have the same machine type?

Comment: Not for GKE. To be clear, KUBE_MAX_PD_VOLS is a workaround that doesn't address other scheduler/performance concerns. Rather than plumb it through, GKE will probably wait to pick up the change in scheduler. If you want to test it in the meantime you can run a cluster on [GCE](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/gce/).